# Soyuz launcher support

Tags: soyuz-launcher

On the launch pad, why is the Soyuz launch vehicle supported in the middle by large arms, rather than resting on its base, as with other launch vehicles?

Answer (score 2):

It is a pretty elegant solution. With the counterweights, as it starts to liftoff the weights drop the arms off, meaning there is no need to build motors for it.

Since they build their pads on the edge of a cliff, this leaves the bottom sort of hanging out, no need for work to redirect the thrust.